# How to make Scrapy crawl in DFS Order

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy code where the structure is like

1. parse()
2. parse(2)
3. parse(3)

I want the scrapy to crawl the pages in dfs order i.e all the 3 links first followed by 2 and then 1. But scrapy doesn't crawl that way. I have tried all the ways to achieve this but unable to get the solution. Can someone suggest me the correct way to get this done

Ex:

```
def parse(self, response):

   print "url1"
   yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse2)

def parse2(self, response):

   print "url2"
   yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse3)

def parse3(self, response):

   print "url3"

   # Do something


Output should be something like

url1
    url2
        url3
        ....
        ....
        ....
    url2
        url3
        ....
        ....
    url2
        url3
        ....
        ....
url1
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you check https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=order#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order ?

Comment: It didn't work. Tried both ways but it is crawling only in bfs order

Comment: If you reduce speed by using CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN   = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
or using depth-priority ... I you provide a complete example I can try different settings here